# How to run Python code in Cloud Functions with a timer

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

Got python 3.x code that I would like to run every hour. What option is available to achieve this with Google Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a job on Google Cloud Scheduler to call the end point of your Cloud Function.
https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler